# Can we bulk mint NFTs on cNFT standard using bubblegum program?

Tags: nft, cnft, bubblegum

I want to mint bulk NFTs given a set of receiver addresses on cNFT standard using the [bubblegum program](https://developers.metaplex.com/bubblegum). Is there a way to achieve this?